# Concourse get bitbucket resource error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON

Tags: json, get, yaml, bitbucket, concourse

I'm trying to create a pipeline with concourse, but I'm facing an unexpected json error.
Could someone please help me out to figure where the problem is and how to solve it?
Below, you'll find related files and information's.

Many thanks for your time.

**Command**

sudo fly -t tutorial set-pipeline -c pipeline.yml -p simple-task -l my-vars.yml my-key.yml --verbose

**Error:**

```
2020/06/08 23:31:28 GET /api/v1/info HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip


2020/06/08 23:31:28 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 82
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2020 21:31:28 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Concourse-Version: 6.2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{"version":"6.2.0","worker_version":"2.2","external_url":"http://localhost:8080"}

2020/06/08 23:31:28 GET /api/v1/teams/main/pipelines/simple-task/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip


2020/06/08 23:31:28 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2020 21:31:28 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Concourse-Version: 6.2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
```

**pipeline.yml**

```
---
resources:
    name: source-code
    type: git
    source: ((pipelines_source))
jobs:
  - name: job
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: source-code
        trigger: true
      - task: simple-task
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: registry-image
            source: { repository: aretelabs/nomad-resource }
          run:
            path: echo
            args: ["Ready"]
```

**my-vars.yml**

```
---
pipelines_source:
      branch: master
      uri: git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git 
      private_key: ((private_key))
```

**my-key.yml**

```
private_key: -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
... blablabla ...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `-` in front of the resource name. You need to format **pipeline.yml** file in following way to indicate valid key-value pairs since the YAML gets converted to JSON.

```
---
resources:
  - name: source-code
    type: git
    source: ((pipelines_source))
jobs:
  - name: job
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: source-code
        trigger: true
      - task: simple-task
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: registry-image
            source: { repository: aretelabs/nomad-resource }
          run:
            path: echo
            args: ["Ready"]
```